# SQL Query to find details of branches & Number of account in each branch

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am Using Oracle11G Database. There are Three Tables which are Employee, Bank_Branch & Account.

Employee(**EID**, ENAME) 
BANK_BRANCH (**BCODE**, BNAME) 
ACCOUNT(**ACC_No**, ***EID***, ***BCODE***, AMOUNT, Account_TYPE)

```
*EMP-TABLE*
''''''''''
EID      ENAME
1        RAM
2        SHYAM
3        RAKESH

*BRANCH-TABLE*
""""""""""""""
BCODE    BNAME
B001     Dhaka
B002     Munger
B003     KOTA

*ACCOUNT-TABLE*
"""""""""""""""
ACC_NO EID  BCODE  AMOUNT  ACCOUNT_TYPE
  1     1   B001   5000    Saving
  2     1   B001   2000    Current
  3     2   B003   4000    Saving
  4     3   B002   2000    Saving
  5     3   B002   3000    Current
  6     4   B001   1200    Saving
```

Here Each Employee can have max two types of account. Saving Or Current. I have to find details of branches and Number of account in each branch.

```
MY OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS 
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
BCODE   BNAME  TOTAL_ACCOUNT
B001    DHANKA      3
B002    Munger      2
B003    KOTA        1  

I have tried multiple queries but they didn't work... Please Help..
Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: I recommend that  you include some example data and the output that you want to get out of the query assuming that example data was in the tables. For me, reading your description, it is not clear what you need and an example might make it clear.

Comment: If you're using Oracle11G, why did you put `mysql` in the tags?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: "I have tried multiple queries but they didn't work" Please [edit] the question and include the queries **you** have tried and explain why they did not work and what you expect them to produce.

Comment: do you know about aggregate function? I wonder why you mention " Each Employee can have max two types of account" how does it affect output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the BANK_BRANCH and ACCOUNT tables, the summarise using count(1) and GROUP BY.

```
select
   BANK_BRANCH.BCODE
  ,BANK_BRANCH.BNAME
  ,count(1) as TOTAL_ACCOUNT
from BANK_BRANCH
left join ACCOUNT
  on BANK_BRANCH.BCODE = ACCOUNT.BCODE
group by
   BANK_BRANCH.BCODE
  ,BANK_BRANCH.BNAME
```